# Wireless USB devices compatible with Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, usb, 64-bit, wireless-networking

I want to upgrade my Vista 64-bit edition to Windows 7 64-bit, so I've installed and run the Windows 7 Compatibility Test. The only item that is being highlighted as incompatible is my Zyxel G-202 wireless usb network device.

Does anyone know of a wireless USB device that is compatible with Windows 7 64-bit?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/compatibility/Browse.aspx?type=Hardware&category=Networking&os=64-bit&subcategory=Wireless%20Network%20Cards&showallcats=true&compat=compatible) is a list of all wireless adapters compatible with Vista 64. These should also be compatible with Windows 7 since to my knowledge the network stack hasn't changed much.

Comment: Thank you for the list, however it seems that although, as you say, nothing much should have changed between Vista and 7, the majority of usb wireless adapters with Vista 64 drivers (such as my own, a Zyxel G-202) are not compatible. I've done some research and there are many forum posts from users in my situation (migrating from Vista to 7) that find themselves with incompatible devices.

Comment: Have you tried running the installer in compatibility mode setting it to Vista, maybe a long shot but still...

Comment: I'm a bit nervous of upgrading to 7, just in case things don't work - as the wireless usb is currently the only way I can connect the machine to the web.

Answer (score 0):

Well my experience differs. Just bought a Netgear Wireless-N 300 USB Adapter WN 111 v.2 and Windows 7 did not recognize the adapter although it seemed to install all right. Telephone support at Netgear tells me, they don't have a driver yet that works with Windows 7. So I am returning it. Anyone a real life experience with a USB WLAN adapter that really works?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to recommend any over any others - Nearly all modern wireless adapters that are on the market right now (especially N based devices as these are newer) are fully compatible with Windows 7.

If you want to spend a bit extra, look for the made for / compatible with Windows 7 logo... Generally these are a bit more expensive as testing costs money, but you are guaranteed that it is fully compatible in any/every scenario. (x86 and x64)

[image]

Although, personally for me, for home machines, I just look for the cheapest place that has a Realtek chip on it - nearly all wireless cards from unknown manufacturers contain one of a handfull of reference designs and I have never had a problem with the Realtek ones*.

*In Windows Vista, the built in driver is rubbish and broken at connecting to WPA2 based networks - I always have a copy of the latest version (unbranded and direct from Realtek) available on my usb stick. Even though Windows 7's built in support is better, I would still use the newest version from their site.

Answer (score 0):

Xyxel  WUSB600N has a driver for win7-64bit, but it is not on the CD, you have to get it from the Xyxel website.